# SplitPane get selected pane

Tags: java, javafx

I have a splitpane with each containing a anchorpane with a tableview (paneA paneB). By clicking on the button "Show" I want to open a new view depending on the selected side of the split pane.

E.G.

```
Pane A     |    Pane B
patient 1  |    patient a
patient 2  |    patient b

(ShowButon)
```

What I imagine.

```
private void showButton(ActionEvent e) {
  if (is selected paneA){
     get selected row
     open view conataining information from selected row paneA
  else if (is selected paneB) {
     get selected row
     open view conaining information from selected row paneB
  }
}
```

For a tab view for example you can easily get the selected tab. Now is something like this possible for a splitpane?

I hope it is now more understandable.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask] and then [edit] your question to provide some code, preferably a [mcve]. From your description it's hard to understand what you mean by "selected" pane - do you want to get the left child of the splitpane? Do you want to get the one that has the focus? Are "patient 1" and "patient 2" children of pane A or model entries?

Comment: Not possible; there simply is no selection of the items of a `SplitPane`; you may possibly be able to work around this by using focus...

Comment: you seem to have a problem with the mental model of your requirement: "selected" is a technical term that's applicable only if the node you apply it on has api that supports it (which most don't) So the first step would be to think about what you really mean by "selected" and then go to the java doc (and/or decent tutorials) to find out how that which controls support that notion.

Comment: Do you have a hint how I could do a work around to somehow get the last chosen pane? Is there a possibility to add a listener to the mouse which pane gets clicked, so I can always store the last focused pane?

Comment: define "chosen"

Answer (score 1):

I do not know of any way to watch which side of a `SplitPane` has been clicked on, but you can certainly register a listener on the `Node` you've placed within each side.

The example below creates a very simple interface with a `VBox` in each of the two `SplitPane` sides. We simply listen for a click on either `VBox` and respond accordingly:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.SplitPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class PaneSelectionExample extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // Simple interface
        VBox root = new VBox(5);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        SplitPane splitPane = new SplitPane();
        VBox.setVgrow(splitPane, Priority.ALWAYS);

        // Two VBoxes with Labels
        VBox box1 = new VBox() {{
            setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);
            getChildren().addAll(
                    new Label("One"),
                    new Label("Two"),
                    new Label("Three")
            );
        }};

        VBox box2 = new VBox() {{
            setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);
            getChildren().addAll(
                    new Label("One"),
                    new Label("Two"),
                    new Label("Three")
            );
        }};

        // Now, we'll add an EventListener to each child pane in the SplitPane to determine which
        // has been clicked
        box1.setOnMouseClicked(event -> System.out.println("Left Pane clicked!"));
        box2.setOnMouseClicked(event -> System.out.println("Right Pane clicked!"));

        // Add our VBoxes to the SplitPane
        splitPane.getItems().addAll(box1, box2);

        root.getChildren().add(splitPane);

        // Show the Stage
        primaryStage.setWidth(300);
        primaryStage.setHeight(300);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

---

**Incoming Opinion Alert**

*While this may solve your immediate question, you may want to revisit your decision to have only one `Show` button. Is the user going to expect that and understand which details the `Show` button will present?*

*It may be a better idea to have a separate `Show` button in each pane of the `SplitPane`; that seems more "standard" to me.*